# GPU memory allocation for video

Tags: opengl, directx, cuda, gpu

Is it possible to allocate some memory on the GPU without cuda?

i'm adding some more details...
i need to get the video frame decoded from VLC and have some compositing functions on the video; I'm doing so using the new SDL rendering capabilities.
All works fine until i have to send the decoded data to the sdl texture... that part of code is handled by standard malloc which is slow for video operations.

Right now i'm not even sure that using gpu video will actually help me

Comment: That changes everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be clear: are you are trying to accomplish **real time video processing?** Since your latest update changed the problem considerably, I'm adding another answer.

The "*slowness*" you are experiencing could be due to several reasons. In order get the "*real-time*" effect (in the perceptual sense), you must be able to process the frame and display it withing 33ms (approximately, for a 30fps video). This means you must decode the frame, run the compositing functions (as you call) on it, and display it on the screen within this time frame.

If the compositing functions are too CPU intensive, then you might consider writing a GPU program to speed up this task. But **the first thing** you should do **is determine where the bottleneck of your application is** exactly. You could strip your application momentarily to let it decode the frames and display them on the screen (do not execute the compositing functions), just to see how it goes. If its slow, then the decoding process could be using too much CPU/RAM resources (maybe a bug on your side?).

I have used **FFMPEG and SDL** for a similar project once and I was very happy with the result. [**This tutorial**](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html) shows to do a basic *video player* using both libraries. Basically, it opens a video file, decodes the frames and renders them on a surface for displaying.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via [Direct3D 11 Compute Shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Direct3D#Direct3D_11) or [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).  These are similar in spirit to CUDA.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. You can allocate memory in the GPU through OpenGL textures.

Answer (score 1):

Only indirectly through a graphics framework.
You can use OpenGL which is supported by virtually every computer.

You could use a vertex buffer to store your data. Vertex buffers are usually used to store points for rendering, but you can easily use it to store an array of any kind. Unlike textures, their capacity is only limited by the amount of graphics memory available.

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html has a good tutorial on how to read and write data to vertex buffers, you can ignore everything about drawing the vertex buffer.